# Parse Json data in Angular 6 Template

Tags: html, css, angular, angularjs-directive

I am getting JSON response as below,

```
{
  "Meta Data" : {
    "ticker" : "NEE",
    "datapoints" : 320,
    "credit cost" : 320,
    "Time Zone" : "America/New_York",
    "last refreshed" : "06/17/2019 at 09:27AM ET"
  },
  "Realtime Stock price" : [ {
    "ticker" : "NEE",
    "date" : "20190614",
    "minute" : "15:58:01",
    "volume" : 1028861,
    "price" : 207.02,
    "timezone" : "EDT",
    "timezone_name" : "America/New_York",
    "gmt_offset" : -14400
  }, {
    "ticker" : "NEE",
    "date" : "20190614",
    "minute" : "15:57:00",
    "volume" : 996057,
    "price" : 207.14,
    "timezone" : "EDT",
    "timezone_name" : "America/New_York",
    "gmt_offset" : -14400
  }]}
```

This is my code,

```
  allPrice: Array<object> = [];
getShareData(){
    this.dataservice.getSharePrice().subscribe(data=>{
      this.allPrice=data['Realtime Stock pric'];
      console.log("Show Price"+JSON.stringify(this.allPrice[1]));

    })
  }
```

But I not getting price value in my Template. I tride with map as well

```
this.allPrice=data['Realtime Stock pric'].map(d=>d.price);
```

But that is also not working.

What can I do ? Please suggest

Comment: `Realtime Stock price`, not `Realtime Stock pric`

Comment: That's what happens when you don't respect conventions, you end up making mistakes that aren't picked up by your IDE ... Consider closing your question as the issue is simply a typo.

Comment: Yes that is my bad. Thank you @Maryannah for your quick fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
this.allPrice=data['Realtime Stock price'];
```

not

```
this.allPrice=data['Realtime Stock pric'];
```

Comment: A comment (mine) already explains the issue. Consider upvoting the comment instead of posting an answer to get points.

Comment: @Maryannah I have upvoted your answer. It was a silly mistake of mine. Pure typo error.

Comment: @SUBHASISMONDAL I know, I'm not talking to you, I'm talking to Badrooo. I'm giving him the best practices on Stack overflow. As for you, as I have told you, you should delete your question : `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.`

Comment: @Maryannah i did not see your comment

Comment: @Badrooo of course, then I'm sure you wouldn't mind deleting your answer :)

Comment: I have this message :You cannot delete this accepted answer